# MDX last order date and last order value

Tags: ssas, mdx

I've googled but I cannot get the point

I've a fact table like this one

fact_order

id, id_date, amount id_supplier
1    1        100    4
2    3        200    4

where id_date is the primary key for a dimension that have

id  date     month
1 01/01/2011 january
2 02/01/2011 january
3

I would like to write a calculated member that give me the last date and the last amount for the same supplier.

Answer (score 0):

Last date and last amount -- it's a maximum values for this supplier?

If "yes", so you can create two metrics with aggregation "max" for fields id_date and amount.
And convert max id_date to appropriate view in the following way:

```
CREATE MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.[Measures].[Max Date]
 AS 
IIF([Measures].[Max Date Key] is NULL,NULL,
STRTOMEMBER("[Date].[Calendar].[Date].&["+STR([Measures].[Max Date Key])+"]").name), 
VISIBLE = 1  ;
```

It will works, If maximum dates in your dictionary have maximum IDs. In my opinion You should use date_id not 1,2,3..., but 20110101, 20110102, etc.

If you don't want to obtain max values - please provide more details and small example.

Comment: ok my explanation was poor this is the fact: I have a fact table that is something like order detail every row contains id_ to the measure tables for exaple ID_Client that is the idenfier for the measure Client and I have an ID_Date that is 20010101 20010102 and so on that is the logical key with the Measure Date that contains year trimestr and so one translated. I need for example to be able to output a report with every row contains client, latest order to that client, value of the latest order. I can't figure out how to do this